# What does yield do in this Ruby method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a bit of old code in a legacy app which uses `yield` in a way that I don't understand. I could use some help with an explanation. I've read most of the SO results on Ruby `yield` but don't understand it in this context. Thanks.

```
def find_all_from_source(source_id)
  joins, conditions = invoke_records_from_source(source_id)
  find(:all, :select => “#{self.table_name}”, :joins => joins, :conditions => conditions).each do |record|
    yield record
  end
end

result = {}
model.find_all_from_source(source_id) do |r|
   result[r.id] = {'attribute' => r.attribute }
end
```

Comment: So I added some code related to the comment that @sergio made about missing block.

Answer (score 2):

`find_all_from_source` is evidently meant to be called with a block that processes the records returned by `find` in some way. The `yield` calls that block on each record.

That method could have been written this unidiomatic way to avoid Ruby's hard-to-follow implicit block syntax:

```
def find_all_from_source(source_id, some_more_arguments, &block)
  joins, conditions = invoke_records_from_source(source_id, some_more_arguments)
  find(:all, :select => “#{self.table_name}”, :joins => joins, :conditions => conditions).each do |record|
    block.call record
  end
end
```

Comment: "I'd expect it to fail" - unless `find` returns nothing, which hides the error. Or maybe he thought that the block is an insignificant detail and hid it behind `some_more_arguments`.

Comment: So with the added code block, is the `yield record` being replaced with the `do |r|
   result[r.id] = {'attribute' => r.attribute }
end` block of code? @SergioTulentsev @DaveSchweisguth

Comment: Not "replaced", exactly, but yes, the block runs at that point with the block parameter `r` set to the argument to `yield`, `record`.